# fs.writeFile does not respect the order of execution of functions (it always executes last)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I started tinkering with JavaScript (Node) recently, and I'm having a problem with a function that performs file writing. This function is always executed last, regardless of the calling order, and I can't fix it, could someone help me? (For example, in the code below, the categorySumPrice() function should run after the createAndWriteFixedJsonFile() function, but it runs before)
This is the program:

```
// *********************  CLASSES  ****************

class Produto {
    constructor(id, name, quantity, price, category) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.quantity = quantity
        this.price = price
        this.category = category
    }
}

// *********************  Procedural  *************

// ------ Global variables

// vector of objects produto
var produtos = []
// file name
const fileName = "broken-database.json"
//fixed file name
const fixedFileName = "./arquivo.json"
// file open require
const fs = require("fs")

//Read and Writing modes, like C
/* 
r - Open file for reading
r+ - Open file for reading and writing
rs - Open file for reading synchronous mode
rs+ - Open file for reading and writing, synchronous mode

w - Open file for writing synchronous mode (if not exists file, created that)
wx - Open file for writing (if not exists file, dont created that)
w+ - Open file for writing and reading (if not exists file, created that)
wx+ - Open file for writing and reading (if not exists file, dont created that)

*/

// Fix JSON Part
// open broken database
var jsonFileName = openFile(fileName)
//read json file, fix, if necessary, and create objects produto
readFile(jsonFileName)
//save new JSON file fixed
createAndWriteFixedJsonFile(fixedFileName)

//sum price functions
categorySumPrice()


// *********************  FUNÇÕES  *************

// Open File
function openFile(_file_name) {
    try {
        console.log('********************************')
        console.log('*  Arquivo aberto com sucesso  *')
        console.log('********************************')

        return fs.readFileSync(_file_name, 'utf-8')
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

// Fix JSON File and create objects produto
function readFile(_json_File) {
    // Create produtos objects
    try {

        console.log('********************************')
        console.log('*   Os dados serão corrigidos, *')
        console.log('*   se necessário.             *')
        console.log('********************************')

        const data = JSON.parse(_json_File)

        for (var i in data) {

            produtos[i] = new Produto(parseInt(data[i].id), fixString(data[i].name),
                fixQuantity(data[i].quantity), fixPrice(data[i].price), data[i].category)

        }

        console.log('********************************')
        console.log('*   Dados obtidos com sucesso  *')
        console.log('********************************')
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(`Erro: ${err}`)
    }
}

// create and write fixed Json file
function createAndWriteFixedJsonFile(_fixedFileName) {
    try {
    fs.writeFile(_fixedFileName, JSON.stringify(produtos, null, 2), err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log('********************************')
                console.log('*  Arquivo criado com sucesso  *')
                console.log('********************************')
            }
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}


function fixQuantity(quantityToFix) {
    let quantity

    if (isNaN(quantityToFix)) {
        quantity = 0
    }
    else {
        quantity = parseFloat(quantityToFix)
    }
    return quantity

}

function fixPrice(priceToFix) {
    return parseFloat(priceToFix)
}

// Fix string function
function fixString(stringToFix) {
    // Quatro tipos de erros conhecidos:
    /* 
        "a" por "æ", 
        "c" por "¢", 
        "o" por "ø", 
        "b" por "ß".
    */
    // o /g significará que todos os valores correspondentes serão substituídos.
    // por padrão, replace substitui somente a primeira ocorrência
    stringToFix = stringToFix.replace(new RegExp(/æ/g), "a");
    stringToFix = stringToFix.replace(new RegExp(/¢/g), "c");
    stringToFix = stringToFix.replace(new RegExp(/ø/g), "o");
    stringToFix = stringToFix.replace(new RegExp(/ß/g), "b");

    return stringToFix
}

function categorySumPrice() {
    let estoquePorCategoria = []
    let indice
    let countCategories = 0

    for (var i in produtos) {
        if (i === 0) {
            estoquePorCategoria[countCategories] = { categoria: produtos[i].category, valor: (produtos[i].quantity * produtos[i].price) }
            countCategories++
        }
        else {
            indice = estoquePorCategoria.indexOf(estoquePorCategoria.filter(function (obj) {
                return obj.categoria == produtos[i].category;
            })[0]);
            if (indice != -1) {
                estoquePorCategoria[indice].valor += (produtos[i].quantity * produtos[i].price)
            }
            else {
                estoquePorCategoria[countCategories] = { categoria: produtos[i].category, valor: (produtos[i].quantity * produtos[i].price) }
                countCategories++
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(estoquePorCategoria)
}
```

Comment: So we can help please reduce your code to the minimum, reading ton of unrelated code is not fun, help us help you

Comment: It was my first question, I'll make a note for the next ones, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeFile` is an asynchronous function, which means that it will execute in parallel to other things.  So:

1. You call `writeFile` then it starts writing.
2. The rest of your code continues executing while it's writing.
3. The `writeFile` finishes writing.

In order to have it execute synchronously with your other code you need to use `writeFileSync`.

You should use `writeFile` when the rest of your code isn't dependent on that file and `writeFileSync` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs.writeFileSync`, this will run according to your work flow.

Learn more about it here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefilesync-method/

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFile()` is executed asynchronously meaning that `categorySumPrice()` comes ahead of `createAndWriteFixedJsonFile()` because it takes time to save the file.

To avoid this you need to call `categorySumPrice()` from the callback function in `fs.writeFile()`:

```
// create and write fixed Json file
function createAndWriteFixedJsonFile(_fixedFileName) {
    try {
    fs.writeFile(_fixedFileName, JSON.stringify(produtos, null, 2), err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log('********************************')
                console.log('*  Arquivo criado com sucesso  *')
                console.log('********************************')

                //And now is the time for executing the following:
                categorySumPrice();
            }
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is a way to solve it too, but I decided here by going to writeFileSync